# Parser code not working properly

Tags: java, string, parsing, token

I have trouble in simple parser wrote in Java. This parser is parsing string by-letter and than saves tokens into arraylist, than parser processes that tokens (e.g. 'PUT', or 'STRING:...')

That's my code:

```
package net.ruza;

import java.util.*;

public class SimpleParser
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleParser simpleParser = new SimpleParser();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = "###";

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (input.length() > 1)
        {
            input = sc.nextLine();

            data.addAll(simpleParser.lex(input));
        }

        for (String s : data)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        simpleParser.parse(data);
    }

    public List<String> lex(String parse)
    {
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean stringFound = false;
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

        StringBuilder tok = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c : parse.toCharArray())
        {
            tok.append(c);

            if (tok.toString().equals("put"))
            {
                tokens.add("PUT");

                tok = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else if (tok.toString().equals(" ") && !stringFound)
            {
                tok = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else if (!stringFound && (tok.toString().equals("\"") || tok.toString().equals("'")))
            {
                stringFound = true;

                tok = new StringBuilder();

                System.out.println("String found!");
            }
            else if (stringFound && (tok.toString().equals("\"") || tok.toString().equals("'")))
            {
                tokens.add("STRING:'" + string.toString() + "'");

                System.out.println("String end!");

                tok = new StringBuilder();
                string = new StringBuilder();

                stringFound = false;
            }
            else if (stringFound)
            {
                string.append(c);

                tok = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }

        return tokens;
    }

    public void parse(List<String> tokens)
    {
        System.out.println("Parser invoked!");

        boolean putNext = false;

        for (String s : tokens)
        {
            if (s.equals("PUT"))
            {
                putNext = true;
            }
            else if (putNext && (s.substring(0, 5).equals("STRING") || s.substring(0, 2).equals("NUM")))
            {
                doPrint(s);
            }
            else System.err.println("Invalid token!");
        }
    }

    public void doPrint(String toPrint)
    {
        if (toPrint.substring(0, 5).equals("STRING"))
            System.out.println(toPrint.substring(7, toPrint.length() - 1));
        else if (toPrint.substring(0, 2).equals("NUM"))
            System.out.println(toPrint.substring(4, toPrint.length() - 1));
        else System.err.println("Invalid printable!");
    }
}
```

How to get that code working properly (e.g. tokens={"PUT", "STRING:'Hi!'"} -> prints 'Hi!'..)

I will be glad for answer!

Comment: "I will be glad for answer!" To what question?  Please include your question in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it! It was because of too conditional processing.

I needed to remove some 'if' statements and it get working after some time.